# Как в Canvos добавить 3D объект?

Tags: unity3d

Здраствуйте, хочу поместить в Canvos 3D объект, когда я его добавляю, при старте игры объект становится плоских и черным. Что с этим можно сделать ?

Comment: `RawImage`.....

Comment: Ага, именно canv**O**s